# get filename from filepath without extension in sql server

Tags: sql

please let me know how to get filename only without extension from the filepath.
Like

I have filepath in database is

```
Attachments\abc\demo.jpg
```

I would like to get only

```
 demo
```

how do i can get this without extension and full path.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way to do what you want.

```
DECLARE @Path varchar(200);
DECLARE @FNamePos INT;
DECLARE @ExtensionStart INT;

SELECT  
    @Path = 'Attachments\abc\demo.jpg'
    , @FNamePos = CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@Path))
    , @ExtensionStart=CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@Path))

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Path,LEN(@Path)-@FNamePos+2,@FnamePos-@ExtensionStart-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte_sample AS
(
    SELECT filepath = '/rootfolder/subfolder/myfile.csv'
)

SELECT
     filepath
    ,fullfilename        = REVERSE(SUBSTRING( REVERSE(filepath), 1, CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(filepath)) - 1 ))
    ,filenamenoextension = REVERSE(SUBSTRING( REVERSE(filepath), CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(filepath)) + 1, CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(filepath)) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(filepath)) -1 ))
FROM [cte_sample];
```